# My system is missing a "System Serial Number"

Tags: windows-7, bios, wmic, serial-number

> No, it is not about the Windows serial key and/or activation.

After reading this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/21548747/1190388 ) about `dmidecode` and system serial numbers, I came across [this article on Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/558124) pages. The article says that I can find my serial number using

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

or the VB script:

```
On Error Resume Next 
Dim strComputer
strComputer = InputBox("Enter the name of the computer:") 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colSMBIOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_SystemEnclosure") 
For Each objSMBIOS in colSMBIOS
MsgBox strComputer & ": " & objSMBIOS.SerialNumber
Next
```

I tried doing so, but the result was a blank line.

```
C:\Users\hjpotter92>wmic bios get serialnumber
SerialNumber



C:\Users\hjpotter92>wmic csproduct get name
Name



C:\Users\hjpotter92>
```

So, is this expected behaviour? I executed the commands as Administrator.

Comment: What make and model of machine is this?

Comment: Is your computer a brand name? Most likely, the builder simply didn't assign the machine a serial number.

Comment: @zelanix Assembled system. DX58SO motherboard.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, not a branded system. All parts were purchased separately and assembled at home

Comment: What is the model number and company name of your computer mother board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you built the system and you didn't assign it a serial number, then how could it have a system serial number?

Comment: When trying to solve a problem always look at the simplest things first

Comment: But I've another machine which boots into debian and `dmidecode` gives me the serial numbers for it. That machine was also assembled at home.

Comment: @hjpotter92 The manufacturer of that motherboard likely configured it to give the motherboard serial number as a system serial number if it wasn't assigned one by the builder. But, obviously, that's not an actual system serial number. (There's already a place the mainboard serial number goes.)